# Currency formatting Yen in Internet Explorer has extra symbols "ï¿¥"

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsp, character-encoding

I'm just using:

```
NumberFormat cfLocal = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN.toString());
```

And it works fine on most devices/browsers/currencies except in IE and Yen I'm getting a few extra characters - could it be a weird encoding being sent, or browser specific settings screwing up handling of the ¥ symbol?

The output looks like this:

> ï¿¥15,180

Would appreciate any leads or tips.

**Edit:**
I am outputting the values with JSP. JSP file is defined with this preamble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: What HTML presentation technology are you using? JSP?

Comment: Yes JSP, updated question with this info.

Comment: Why are you mixing ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no encoding expert but your XML appears to say one thing and your content-type another - try setting both to UTF-8.

If your data is coming from outside the application (e.g. a database, file, etc.), what is the encoding of the source? For example, a MySQL database may have a different character set specified.

If you are using a web server like Apache, is that changing the encoding? For example you can have a httpd.conf directive to set the default character set:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

It would be worth checking the HTTP Headers in the browser to see what is actually being sent to the browser, and work back from there.

EDIT

Thinking about it more, I'm not sure if the XML encoding is necessarily the problem. It would probably be best to check the headers first, and compare it to the the html being produced.

Comment: The `encoding` parameter in the XML declaration is wrong and should be fixed in any case (from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8) to match other parts of the preamble.